# Value in button?

Tags: angularjs

I have the value `{{data[0].pageCount}}`.

It displays a number and it works fine.

But it doesn't work when I do:

```
<button  class='btn button-next' ng-disabled="currentPage >= {{data[0].pageCount}}" ng-click="getPage(currentPage=currentPage+1)">
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

try this,

```
 <button  class='btn button-next' ng-disabled="currentPage >= data[0].pageCount" ng-click="getPage(currentPage=currentPage+1)">
```

Comment: `>` should be escaped. I would use a function defined  in the controller scope to avoid this escape.